# horizontal alignment of div tags in header

Tags: html, css, css-float

I am trying to make all my div tags to be horizontally alignment in my header....
but right now they are all vertically alignment...
how to make it horizontally aligned....

providing my fiddle below

http://jsfiddle.net/TdcRJ/4/[image]

```
<div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container-header">
            <!-- <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </a> -->
            <!-- <div class="clear"></div> -->

            <div class="companyLogo" style="width: 1009px;">
                <div style="
    display: inline-block;
">
                    <a class="brand" href="&lt;?= HOME_URL ;?&gt;" style="">
                    Company LOGO
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div style="clear: left;">
                    <p>47657 Lakeview Blvd</p>
                    <p>Fremont CA 94538</p>
                    <p>510-657-8981</p>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <p>welcome xyz! xyz@defie.co</p>
                </div>

                <div class="inline" style="padding-top: 12px;">

                        <ul class="homePageLists" style="">
                            <li style="padding-bottom: 5px; list-style: none; color: #333;">
                                <a style="color: #333;" href="http://www.w3schools.com/" target="_blank">
                                  <img alt="squareList" style="margin-right: 10px;" id="logo" src="http://intra.defie.co/images/cube_menu.png">
                                   Menu
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li style="padding-bottom: 5px; list-style: none; color: #; ">
                                <a style="color: #653921;" href="http://www.w3schools.com/" target="_blank">
                                  <img alt="squareList" style="margin-right: 10px;" id="logo" src="http://intra.defie.co/images/cube_inventory.png">
                                  Inventory
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li style="padding-bottom: 5px; list-style: none; color: #653921; ">
                                <a style="color: #653921;" href="http://www.w3schools.com/" target="_blank">
                                  <img alt="squareList" style="margin-right: 10px;" id="logo" src="http://intra.defie.co/images/cube_inventory.png">
                                  BOM List
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li style="padding-bottom: 5px; list-style: none; color: #653921; ">
                                <a style="color: #653921;" href="http://www.w3schools.com/" target="_blank">
                                    <img alt="squareList" style="margin-right: 10px;" id="logo" src="http://intra.defie.co/images/cube_inventory.png">
                                    Sub BOM List
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li style="padding-bottom: 5px; list-style: none; color: #9e1c20; ">
                                <a style="color: #9e1c20;" href="http://www.w3schools.com/" target="_blank">
                                    <img alt="squareList" style="margin-right: 10px;" id="logo" src="http://intra.defie.co/images/cube_product.png">
                                    Product
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li style="padding-bottom: 5px; list-style: none; color: #ff5100; ">
                                <a style="color: #ff5100;" href="http://www.w3schools.com/" target="_blank">
                                    <img alt="squareList" style="margin-right: 10px;" id="logo" src="http://intra.defie.co/images/cube_customer.png">
                                    Customer List
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li style="padding-bottom: 5px; list-style: none; color: #184179;">
                                <a style="color: #ff5100;" href="http://www.w3schools.com/" target="_blank">
                                    <img alt="squareList" style="margin-right: 10px;" id="logo" src="http://intra.defie.co/images/cube_vender.png">
                                    Vendor List
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>

                </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->

                <div>
                    <p>ABC Systems</p>
                    <p>1234 lakeview Blvd</p>
                    <p>CA 94538</p>
                    <p>510-657-8981</p>
                </div>


            </div>




            <div class="login-container">





                <form method="post" action="/Account" class="bs-docs-example form-horizontal" id="createUserForm">
                    <div class="login-box">
                        <div class="login-label">Email</div><div class="login-input"><input type="text" name="email" value=""></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="login-box">
                        <div class="login-label">Password</div><div class="login-input"><input type="password" name="password" value=""></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="login-button">
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </form>

                        </div>          <div class="clear"></div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the css style `float:left;` in all DIVs that you want to make horizontally align.

Comment: Try this.
http://jsfiddle.net/TdcRJ/11/
Your code is not very clean so it is a bit harder to read.

Answer (score 0):

you can put float:left or float:right in all Divs